# How to prevent an IP range having access outside the local network (i.e. block internet access) on TP-Link Archer

Tags: networking, router, security, home-networking

I have the TP-Link Archer VR900. I have set up interface groups so my wired network has a separate IP range to everything else.

I want to be able to block internet access from clients in this group so I can put a very old PC on my intranet without it getting internet access, so no auto-updates get triggered until I can finish transferring files.
I don't want to plug it in then block it once I know the IP address, I want to block an entire IP range like 192.168.2.xxx from having external access.

It seems like it should be an obvious feature but I cannot find how.

Comment: If the router doesn't support this feature in the firmware, statically set the "old PC" nic outside the DHCP pool. When you get to the default gateway section **leave it blank**. The PC will not know where to send packets to reach the internet.